# Python script to convert pcap to csv?

Tags: python

I used the below code to convert a pcap file to csv file with the given columns. The output csv file. Code doesn't give any error. But no output.
can you help please to find the error

```
import os
import csv
import subprocess
startdir= '/root/Desktop/Files/'
outdir = '/root/Desktop/Outcsv'
suffix= 'Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.pcap'

def decode_to_file(cmd, in_file, new_suffix):
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
fileName = outdir + '/' + in_file[len(startdir):-len(suffix)] + "Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.csv"
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(fileName), exist_ok=True)
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(fileName, 'w'))
for line_bytes in proc.stdout:
    line_str = line_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    csv_writer.writerow(line_str.strip().split(','))

for root,dirs, files, in os.walk(startdir):
for name in files:
    if name.endswith(suffix):
        continue
    in_file=os.path.join(root,name)
    out_file = outdir + '/' + in_file[len(startdir):-len(suffix)] + "Emotet-infection-with-Gootkit.csv"
    cmd = 'tshark -r "{}" -T fields -e frame.time_delta_displayed -e frame.len -e wlan.sa - e wlan.da _E separator=, _E header=y > "{}"'.format(in_file, out_file)
    csv_writer = csv.writer(open(out_file, 'w'))
    print (cmd)
    os.system(cmd)`
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's writing the file to `/root/Desktop/Outcsv/`

Comment: yes i have checked it but no the file is not exist

Comment: i found now the csv file it was just a matter of path but the csv file is empty